# App launches when running unit tests (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp

I am testing a solution that includes a UWP app. None of the tests actually reference the project with the UWP app. But when I hit the "Run all Tests" button in Visual Studio Test Explorer, it launches the UWP app.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Some googling revealed a [thread here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/730446/when-i-run-unit-tests-it-launches-my-uwp-app.html), but it was frankly useless.

Comment: can you list out the steps you've taken to create the unit tests project? and also what unit test library are you using?

Comment: Hi, This should be related to the startup project of the solution, you can try to set the startup project as a unit test project before running the test.